# How to use SSL websocket with remote debugging on Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging, chrome-devtools-protocol

Hope doing well.
I am going to use SSL web socket for remote debugging on Google Chrome.
But in regular, we are using ws://127.0.0.1:9222 for the remote debugging.

I will appreciate if you could please help me.
Thank you.

ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/b0b8a4fb-bb17-4359-9533-a8d9f3908bd8
to
wss://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/b0b8a4fb-bb17-4359-9533-a8d9f3908bd8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome remote debugging port does not support WSS connection (nor does the HTTP/JSON endpoints support HTTPS).

This is probably since from Google's perspective, CDP (Chrome Debugging Protocol) is for debugging and testing, so SSL is not needed.